# C# xamarin get resource.id in function

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, listview, xamarin

I created a function. In the function I am using a ListView, but when I do:

```
Listview1 = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.Listview1);
```

It can't find the Id. What can I do???

Comment: Can you post the code from your axml page... and full code from your activity?

Comment: It doesn't seems to work! But can I use the defined FindViewById in a function when the FindViewById isn't present in the function?

Comment: Please edit your question and post full code, and community will be able to help you.